# Using a stored TimeLapse stored in a datatable inside a php while loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, settimeout

I am trying to display images from a database with a time delay between each image. The time delay is selectable from the user interface
and stored in seconds in the same record as the image. I aalready have the images displaying but I need to incororate the dynamic time delay.

The time delay is stored in a field named "TimeLapse". Below I have tried to used the content of "TimeLapse as $HoldTime each time
the while loop display a new image.

Image one has a TimeLapse of "5000".
Image two has a TimeLapse of "15000".

But it looks like it's only using the first TimeLapse of 5000 for both images."

Can anyone see how I can do this.

PHP CODE

```
while($row_fb = mysqli_fetch_array($fb)){ ?>
    <?php $url = $ImagePath.''.$row_fb['SignageImageName'];
    $HoldTime = $row_fb['TimeLapse']?>
    <div class="outer">
    <div class="banner-container">

    <div id="wrapper">
    <a><img src="/<?php echo $url;?>" class="responsive"/></a>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
(function() {
    var a = $('.outer').children();
    var index = 0;
    run()
  
    function run() {
      a.filter('.active').fadeOut(500).removeClass('active');
      a.eq(index).fadeIn(500).addClass('active');
      index = (index + 1) % a.length;
      setTimeout(run, <?php echo $HoldTime;?>);
    }
  })();
```

Comment: @Dharman Hi. what's the issue with thanking others for their help, it's polite.

Comment: Obviously if you're setting the value of `$HoldTime` in a loop and then using it outside a loop, it will have the value of the last loop iteration.

Comment: It's completely unnecessary. We think of Stack Overflow like Wikipedia. Any fluff like this distracts from the actual content

Comment: @miken32 Hi, Your right. If I put the java script inside the loop it messes up the display. Can you give any advice on how I should be doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the delay time into an [HTML `data-` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) and read it in the JavaScript to set the delay. (Note use of [alternative syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) and [short echo tags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php), this makes your PHP code more readable when mixed with HTML.)

```php
<?php while($row = $fb->fetch_array()): ?>

<div class="outer">
    <div class="banner-container" data-delay-time="<?=$row['TimeLapse']?>">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <a>
                <img src="/<?=$ImagePath . $row['SignageImageName']?>" class="responsive"/>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php endwhile ?>
```

The JS has been cleaned up to eliminate any dependency on variables from outside the function. Instead it just looks for the active banner's next sibling, looping to the beginning if it doesn't have one. Some test HTML is included for a runnable example.

```js
(function() {
    $("div.outer div.banner-container").hide();
    run();

    function run() {
        // get a list of all the banners
        var banners = $("div.outer div.banner-container");
        if (!banners.length) {
            return;
        }
        // active is the one with "active" class, or the first one
        var active = banners.filter(".active").first();
        if (!active.length) {
          active = banners.first();
        }
        // get the next one or loop to the beginning again
        var next = active.next("div.banner-container");
        if (!next.length) {
            next = banners.first();
        }
        active.fadeOut(500).removeClass("active");
        next.fadeIn(500).addClass("active");
        // get the delay time from the data-delay-time attribute
        setTimeout(run, next.data("delayTime"));
    }
})();
```

```css
.active {
    background: blue;
    color: white
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="outer">
  <div class="banner-container" data-delay-time="1000">foo</div>
  <div class="banner-container" data-delay-time="2000">bar</div>
  <div class="banner-container" data-delay-time="6000">baz</div>
  <div class="banner-container" data-delay-time="10000">boo</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your code. If I use it and include the result from the while statement it only displays the first image. In the source code I can see all three images. If I use the example of your "div class-"outer" it works fine. Any ideas why?

Comment: No idea, it's generating almost identical HTML to what you had before, just adding one attribute.